# Info associated to current view in Google Map Android

Tags: android, google-maps

Does anybody know a way to get a list of information associated to the current view used in Google Map in Android? Let's say that I wanna know all the pharmacies present in the current view... is there a way to retrieve this list from the current view?

Like:

- pharmacy 1 : name / location on map
- pharmacy 2 : name / location on map
- etc.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. If you find that a response answers your question, please accept it by clicking on the checkmark next to it. Once you have more repoints, you should also upvote responsess that you find useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yea, you need to use the [google places api](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/) to get information like this.

Comment: Thank you, so would this require to use the Google Map Javascript with android? http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/android_v3.html

Comment: I don't know about the details because I've never used it myself. But if that's what the documentation says to do, then I imagine that's what you should do.